# problems in import data from .csv to excel 2016

Tags: csv, excel-2016

I copy the number 10.6382978723 from a text .csv file into a cell of Excel 2016 and that number is visualized as 106.382.978.723.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the '.' is your Digit Grouping Symbol and not your Decimal Symbol. Check your Regional Options.